# count no of requests hits in access.log

Tags: grep

I have apache running on the production environment which writes request in the access.log. I need to count the number of requests hitting the apache server per minute .
eg:I tried below grep command  to count the no of request hitting the server by the below grep command but its not giving the count instead its printing out the entire log.Can some one please help

```
$ egrep "14/Oct/2014:13:36|14/Oct/2014:13:37" | wc -l access_log

10.8.160.150 - - [14/Oct/2014:13:36:15 -0700] "GET /ads/2011/03/ HTTP/1.0" 200 33812
10.8.161.151 - - [14/Oct/2014:13:36:15 -0700] "GET /ads/2012/10/16/ HTTP/1.0" 200 30854
:::::::
::::;
10.8.170.150 - - [14/Oct/2014:13:37:15 -0700] "GET /ads/2008/07/ HTTP/1.0" 200 33313
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to modify a little.

```
egrep "14/Oct/2014:13:36|14/Oct/2014:13:37" access_log | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go for `egrep` and `wc -l`. Just a basic grep would do the job.

```
grep -c '14/Oct/2014:13:36\|14/Oct/2014:13:37' file
```

OR

```
grep -Ec '14/Oct/2014:13:36|14/Oct/2014:13:37' file
```

Comment: Yes that worked

grep -c '14/Oct/2014:13:36\|14/Oct/2014:13:37' access_log and its giving 1272. Looks like1272 request we are getting per minute. Is this right approach to count the number of requests hitting apache per minute. Do i need to look for any further option??

Appreciate your help!